# Inputstream to string encoding issue

Tags: java

I want to convert inputstream to a String, I am getting some unknown symbols in the string.

I used this code,

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(is, writer,"ISO-8859-1");
String theString = writer.toString();
```

This results in symbols such as ``` ì½ÛrÛJ6xÿGÌ;``êâo;B ð ©»ª"@Øæ©AÒÞÞ7 IhS í­~§7ê'\+3qL ```

please advice.

Comment: what unknown symbols , please show ,so that we could help you

Comment: ì½ÛrÛJ6xÿGÌ;`êâo;B ð ©»ª"@Øæ©AÒÞÞ7  IhS í­~§7ê'\+3qL H like this

Comment: Input is the inputstream object which contains HTML data

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be that the input stream is using a different encoding, did you try using UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Open HTML file source code. Find charset.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=Shift_JIS" />
```

Here charset is Shift_JIS. So code will be like this:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
          IOUtils.copy(is, writer,"Shift_JIS");
          String theString = writer.toString();
```

Comment: I have like this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  and I used UTF-8. I am getting the same

Answer (score 0):

As most answers are keen to point out, there's a 99% chance your issue is caused by the fact that your input is not `iso-latin-1`. That, or there's an encoding issue when you print it (possibly to a terminal that doesn't support `utf-8`, for example?)

If you do not provide us with your input, however, all we can do is try to guess at what its actual encoding might be - something that you're probably going to be able to do much faster than us, given that you actually know what goes in and what's expected to come out (all *we* know is what should not happen, which is not terribly helpful).

This is how you list all supported charsets:

```
for(String name: java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets().keySet())
    System.out.println(name);
```

Armed with this, you should be able to figure out which one is the right one, even if only through an automatable process of elimination.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
  public String getStringFromStream(InputStream inputStream)throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        byteBuffer.flush();
    }
    return new String(byteBuffer.toByteArray());    
}
```

Comment: You should describe what this code does and why it fixes the problem the poster asked.

Comment: It reads the input string from the servlet request inputstream

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
  GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(req.getInputStream());
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip));
  String value = br.readLine();
```